# Not able to get values from the API using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am unable to fetch the values from a `Random quote API`. I don't where this issue is happening. Is it while fetching the content or while returning it to the front end. Could have figured it out had I had access to the logs. And also, I found this API for free on the internet. I still don't understand what the callback param does. 
please refer to the below screen shot

[image: Random Quote API jquery]

This is my html code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#click").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderBy]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(key) {
      $("#quote").append(key[0].content + "<br><p> - " + key[0].title + "</p>");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.position-message {
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
}

.background {
  background-color: maroon;
}

.button-shape {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

.fa-size {}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="quote" class="well position-message"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <button type="button" id="click" class="button-shape"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is a snapshot of my webpage. I am trying to print a random quote in the white area `<div id="quote" class="well position-well">` whenever the button is clicked.

[image: Random Quote webpage]

Answer (score 1):

> Seems that there is something wrong with your server's "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

sorry for the misleading, it seems that the `http://null` is caused by stackoverflow's `Run code snippet`.

```
I made a working copy (no code change besides change the `http` to `https`):

https://jsfiddle.net/qex5y16v/1/
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @shawn. I didn't exactly get what you said as I didn't know what ACAO and CORS were until now.
As per my understanding, I must be on the client side trying to fetch resources from the API, which is not on my server but was built and deployed by someone else on a different server and not monetized. So is the CORS not added in the response from the server side? is that what you meant? And also, how do I debug my page?

Comment: And to add to this, I got the response when I fired the API from `postman`. Can you please let me know how and where to check the ACAO and CORS and how do I debug my page? Because I don't see anything on my browser console

Comment: You can use Chrome or Firefox, right click, inspect, trigger the http request, and look into the "Network" tab.

Comment: Well, I think the problem you met is a little complicated. There are too many uncertain things. Where do you query the url, under the same domain or crossing domain? If you want to do crossing domain query, JSONP should be involved, a JSONP request from 3rd http client like postman should be `http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderBy]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=xxxxxxx`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making a cross-origin request you need to use the second example. Just add `&_jsonp=?` to the API URL. If your webpage is hosted on https (like stacksnippets) then API URL must also be https.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#click").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?", function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="click" class="button-shape">Button</button>
```

> I still don't understand what the callback param does.

You are requesting JSON data from an API that (apparently) does not allow cross origin requests. But they have provided a work around: if you add `_jsonp=myfunc` then the server returns JSONP instead of JSON, which is essentially JavaScript code that wraps JSON data. [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) explains the details.

Comment: thank you for the answer @salman. The query is working, but I am unable to access random quotes as the API accepts only `orderBy` and `posts_per_page` as params. if i use the 'jsonp' param, only the first quote is getting printed.

Comment: I tried adding the callback param `$.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderBy]=2&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=''&_jsonp=?",` The quote response that I am getting is a default one. But when I try firing the API from postman using the same url but with `jsonp`, I am getting the required random responses.

Comment: @GauravThantry you are not good at copy pasting. It should be `orderby`, not `orderBy`. Updated answer.