# How do I set ACAS and CORS request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, esb

So I have been developing a webpage the would give random quotes whenever a user clicks on a button by calling an API. 
Please refer to my previous question for more information [Not able to get values (quotes) from the API using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129916/not-able-to-get-values-quotes-from-the-api-using-jquery/48130807#48130807)

I was told that the reason I couldn't get the response from the API is because my ACAS(Access-control-Allow-Origin) is not set properly in my server and I have to debug it.

Now that I don't much about ACAS or CORS. I have some questions. SO here they are:

**1.** What exactly is ACAS and how is it related to CORS? 
**2.** How do I debug my page and set the ACAS? 
**3.** Does that have to do anything with my jQuery? Or should I configure only my browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can find many documents on the internet
,so I'll just briefly talk about ***CORS***.

When you're sending request to different domain
for example from `a.com` to `b.com`, or `localhost:8080` to `a.com`......
your're making a ***cross-origin HTTP request*** ,
sometime this is not allowed, for example **Ajax** (as you're doing) requests.

Because **XhttpRequest, Fetch** (both are Ajax API) follow ***same-origin policy***, which means by default you can only make requests form the same domain, ex: from `site.com` to `site.com/users`.

The reason they follow the same-origin policy is to prevent ***CSRF*** attack (Cross-site request forgery).

1.So basically you cannot get the result of cross site Ajax request, it will block by browser because of the security issue, unless the response header ***Access-control-Allow-Origin*** is set to allow client's site to send cross site ajax request.  ex: `Access-control-Allow-Origin:*`allow all sites form different domain; `Access-control-Allow-Origin:www.b.com`only allow `www.b.com` domain.

2.Take Chrome for example If the cross site request's result is blocked, it will show on browser's console:

[image]

You need to set the response header in your server, for example I set `Access-control-Allow-Origin:*`, then in browser's "network" console you can see the header is set, and now I can get the Ajax result.

[image]

3. I think nothing should do at client side, all is at server side.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Timothy. But I got the response when I tried firing the API from postman. 
If we go with what you said, that the ACAS is not set on the server side, then that means that I cannot access the API no matter what. But even if that's the case why have they made the API public https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/

Comment: And I am not able to see anything in the browser console when I try to fire the API..

Comment: Making just GET or Post requests are not restricted by same origin policy, but ajax does, because ajax can get the result body.

Answer (score -1):

[Refer to this post as it makes this clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Note also that there are some techniques frequently used in order to bypass CORS like setting up a proxy which acts as a relay for your request or using JSONP instead of JSON.